# Content Search Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template, content-search-web-part

I am creating a page with a Content Search WebPart on it that display's the subsites that contain a specific name.

Query text: **SiteTitle:*[name]* contentclass:STS_Web**

In testing the query the search result preview pane shows me 1 match. **Relevantresults(1)**

Unfortunatly the result doesn't get parsed to the page, no matter what Display Template Control that I use.

Who can help me out of this?

PS: I am using 365: SharePoint Online (365) Plan: Business Premium

Comment: Content Search Webparts are not supported in Business Premium Plans. Instead I created a Sharepoint Hosted app that does exactly that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Search Webparts are not supported in Business Premium Plans. Instead I created a Sharepoint Hosted app that does exactly that job.